# Styling my error message in php. I have half of it styled but can't seem to get the rest to be styled

Tags: php, forms, styles

I have this section of php code which styles the error message

```
echo("<p class=contactformnotsent>Unable to send information because you need to...</p>");
```

How do I also include these lines so that they can be styled in the same way?

```
foreach ($errors as $error)
   { print $error."<br />\n"; }
```

When I do add these lines it gives me a syntax error on the second line which is

```
   { print $error."<br />\n"; }
```

Comment: When you get an error message, it is vital to add it to the question as well, otherwise this is not helpful. Also, please post as well that code in it's context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping them in the paragraph:

```
echo('<p class="contactformnotsent">');
echo('Unable to send information because you need to...');
foreach ($errors as $error) { 
  echo($error . "<br />\n"); 
}
echo('</p>');
```